# Selector CSS JQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it normal that

```
$("#foo a:hover")
```

does not select anything?

I can't use hover cause I need this selector to do that :

```
 $("#foo a:hover").css("color", mycolor);
```

So I wonder if something like

```
 $("#foo").css("a:hover color", mycolor);
```

exist?

**Et What about visited (pseudo class)?**

Comment: You can use hover. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is completely normal. jQuery doesn't have a `:hover` pseudo class.

You can use the `hover` method to bind two event handlers that add and remove the style:

```
$("#foo a").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("color", mycolor);
},function(){
  $(this).css("color", "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

```
$("#foo a").hover(function(){ 
   $(this).css('color','mycolor');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When nothing is currently hovered, yes. Something would need to concurrently be in the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refer to the [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for a list of valid selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should be using the jquery `.hover()` with `$("#foo a")`

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

Yes because that selector will have fired BEFORE you hover anything. For example, if you were to just do:

```
$('#foo')
```

And then later on in the script `append()` foo it will not select anything because it didn't exist.

If you DO want to do something on hover you can do .hover(function(){},function(){})

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the  tag while it's in a psudo-state of being hovered (":hover" is a pseudo-class), so you would need to hover over your  tag and run that script at the same time in order to successfully select the element.